# Crystal Reports grouping by multiple months

Tags: crystal-reports

Can anybody help me group the following data:

```
Name        Order Quantity          Jan         Feb        Mar      Apr
A           10                       Y           Y          N        N
B           12                       Y           N          Y        Y
C           8                        N           N          N        Y
```

The result should look like this:

```
Jan
Name        Order Quantity
A           10
B           12

Feb
Name        Order Quantity
A           10

Mar
Name        Order Quantity
B           12

Apr
Name        Order Quantity
B           12
C           8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying your data source has a separate column for each month? If so,

1. Make a crosstab and group by {Jan}, {Name}, and sum the {Order Quantity}.  Repeat this for all 11 months.
2. If you want to get this all in 1 table, you'd probably have to do some querying in a SQL database of some kind.  i.e. make a union of 12 queries, 1 for each month.